# Not able to create events using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create an Event using Microsoft Graph SDK, as following the document @

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

1.Created "authProvider"

2.Created GraphClient with above AuthProvider

3.Creating Event using

The event is not creating also no exception/error is throwing, Could any one help me here?

Comment: Please share more details: 1. Which flow are you using to access Microsoft Graph? Get access on behalf of a user or without a user? 2. What permissions did you add to your Azure AD app. Please share a screenshot about it. 3. Which authentication provider did you implement? Please point it out in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because this call is being made with same `transactionId` frequently. It avoids unnecessary retries on the server.

It is an optional parameter , just comment out this property and try again. It should work.

Note : This identifier specified by a client app for the server , to avoid redundant POST operations in case of client retries to create the same event and also useful when low network connectivity causes the client to time out before receiving a response from the server for the client's prior create-event request.

Answer (score 0):

More info is required here, as the reply from Allen Wu stated. without any details I would focus my efforts on the authprovider piece and azure app registration piece. as the rest of the example is just sending a post request to graph api.
but what is recommended really depends on what type of application you are trying to build. eg. is it a service daemon, a web app, mobile app, desktop app, single page app, etc.